# Requests not responding on long wait from other IP rather than localhost

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm supposed to raise a **get request** to our rest url which triggers some activity on server and finally returns a response. It may take **more than 30 minutes** to return response. I know that requests doesn't have default timeout. But, When I raise a get request and after 30 minutes even if the server sends back response, requests is not returning. I confirmed that the server sent response from log files. I even tried using request sessions so that my connection will be alive. Still it behaves the same.I'm using `requests v.2.13.0.` Is it the problem with version or with requests. If requests has problem how can i raise a get request which waits till server sends back response? The code is simple anyhow I'm adding for reference.

```
import requests
url="www.abcd/efg/hijkl"
response=requests.get(url) #It hangs at this point even if server sends back response.
```

I've tested the same using postman and google chrome, Both were able to get the response after 30 minutes. Also tried the same by updating the requests to `2.18.4` still same issue.

**EDIT 1:**

The same code works fine if the request is raised from the server to localhost. As per @randomir's suggestion it seems to be issue with `network connection might getting dropped inbetween` but how to handle this from client side as it difficult to implement any server side method.

Comment: `"... even if server sends back response."` How do you know that it does?

Comment: i confirmed it with my server log files. I think i've added that in my question.

Comment: The only reliable way is to have an application-level keep-alive (server writing something back to client every n seconds), and use the read timeout on client. Your connection might be dropped on network layer. You can try setting TCP keep-alive.

Comment: Can you try with [`TCPKeepAliveAdapter`](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#tcpkeepaliveadapter) from [requests toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after so much research and debugging found out the problem. The problem was with the ***proxy in apache webserver*** since we are redirecting the connections there are nearly three redirections from public Ip the connection gets redirected to local web server from ***local web server*** the connection is again redirected to ***api endpoint***. From api connection is redirected again to ***another api***. so now since the api takes long time to respond the apache **webserver** thinks the connection has been lost and returns a proxy error. So If I hit the rest api end point directly it is working fine. Thanks [@randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir) for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077330/6663095) it helped me while digging the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your long-lasting zero-activity network connection might get dropped by intermediate proxies, firewalls, routers, NATs, etc. And the `requests.get()` never finds out about it because it's passively waiting for the response.

One way to prevent this, on a TCP layer, is to use the [TCP keep-alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) (which is usually *off* by default).

In Python, you can configure the TCP keep-alive directly via low-level [`socket.setsockopt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt), but since you're already using `requests`, the easier way is via [`TCPKeepAliveAdapter`](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#tcpkeepaliveadapter) available from the [`requests_toolbelt`](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt) package:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters.socket_options import TCPKeepAliveAdapter

url = '...'
session = requests.Session()
keep_alive = TCPKeepAliveAdapter(idle=120, count=20, interval=30)
session.mount(url, keep_alive)
session.get(url)
```

Comment: How is it different from `keep-alive` in `requests.session()`?

Comment: That's [HTTP keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), a mechanism to reuse a single TCP connection for multiple HTTP requests. TCP keep-alive is lower-level, works on transport, not application layer.

Comment: Btw, HTTP keep-alive works by client sending `Connection: Keep-alive` header field, instructing the server not to close the TCP connection after it delivers the response; thus enabling the client to sent another HTTP request over the same socket. TCP keep-alive is a completely different beast, it sends "empty" (keep-alive) TCP packets a predefined interval just to keep the connection open.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but got same response. But i tried raising the request in the server to localhost in such case it is working fine. I think your suggestion regarding code is partially correct.

Comment: So, it works when you make the request locally (to localhost)? But fails over network? Can you describe your setup (VPS, network, etc)?

Comment: The code is from the [docs](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#tcpkeepaliveadapter).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158093/discussion-between-mani-and-randomir).

Comment: issue resolved and solution found please refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47825964/6663095)